# put res folder on android apk expansion file

Tags: android, apk, google-play

I have an application with a lot of data resources in the res-drawable folder, is it possible to put the res folder in expansion file or i need to make changes in the code? i tried to read about this in the expansion files documantation but cant figure it out.

Comment: what do you mean by **expansion file**?

Comment: @Waqas http://developer.android.com/guide/market/expansion-files.html

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to put the res folder in expansion file

No, sorry.

> i need to make changes in the code

Yes.